# Configuring custom MemoryHandler in dictConfig()

Tags: python, logging

I'm trying to configure my custom class via dictConfig, but every time I get an unconfigured target.

```
class CustomMemoryHandler(logging.handlers.MemoryHandler):
    def __init__(self, capacity, flushLevel, target):
        MemoryHandler.__init__(self, capacity, flushLevel, target)
        log_rec = logging.makeLogRecord({'msg': "***************************",
                                        'level': 40, 'levelno': 40})
        self.emit(log_rec)



logger_settings = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,

    'formatters': {...},
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'level': 'WARNING',
            'formatter': 'common_format'
        },
        'buffer': {
            '()': CustomMemoryHandler,
            #'class': 'logging.handlers.MemoryHandler',
            'capacity': 100,
            'flushLevel': 60,
            'target': 'console',
            'level': 40
        }
    },
    'loggers': {...},
    'filters': {...}
}
```

In the file config.py , in the method def configure_handler(self, config) I found such lines

```
if issubclass(klass, logging.handlers.MemoryHandler) and\
                'target' in config:
```

It turns out that I can't get the right target for my custom class?

Comment: I have ugly solution 
`logging.config.dictConfig(logger_settings)
logger = logging.getLogger('lgr') 
list = logger.handlers list[1].target = list[0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your `buffer` handler like this:

```
    'buffer': {
        'class': '__main__.CustomMemoryHandler',
        'capacity': 100,
        'flushLevel': 60,
        'target': 'console',
        'level': 40
    }
```

using the appropriate module name in place of `__main__` as needed.

Comment: Change '()': CustomMemoryHandler on 'class': '__main__.CustomMemoryHandler' is best. Thanx.